# MFC rich edit control's scroll bar issue

Tags: mfc

I am developing an application for Right to Left reading. I'm inserting a file data into a rich edit control. When the data crosses width of a control, it introduces a horizontal scroll bar. But this scroll bar is put to left end instead of right end.
I tried with some try outs as follows:

1)Changed rich edit styles for Right to Left reading & right aligned text.

2)Sent an explicit Scroll bar message, to set it at right extreme.

3)Retrieved scroll bar's info & set its position to Maximum.
But none worked.

Is there any way to make it right aligned by default?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the code where you "Changed rich edit styles for Right to Left reading & right aligned text. "?

Comment: I have added this code in OnItDialog()     BOOL boRetVal;

 boRetVal = m_RchEdt_Text.ModifyStyleEx(WS_EX_LEFT | WS_EX_LTRREADING, WS_EX_RIGHT | WS_EX_RTLREADING, 0);
 if (0 == boRetVal)
 {
  AfxMessageBox(_T("Failed."));
 }